# gradle plugin provide classpath depedencies

Tags: gradle

In my plugin I am using couple of external dependencies

```
compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:$httpClientVersion"
compile "commons-io:commons-io:$commonsIoVersion"

// tar & xz support
compile "org.tukaani:xz:$xzLibraryVersion"
compile "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:$commonsCompressVersion"

// logging
compile "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:$kotlinLogginVersion"
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:$slf4jSimpleVersion"
```

When I use my plugin I have to provide them as `classpath` dependencies

```
classpath "org.tukaani:xz:$xzLibraryVersion"
classpath "commons-io:commons-io:$commonsIoVersion"
classpath "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:$commonsCompressVersion"
classpath "com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv:gradle-app-environment-plugin:0.1"
classpath "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:$kotlinLogginVersion"
```

Is there a way to escape from it? I mean to allow to set only my plugin dependency and other it provides itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
ext.commonDeps = [
    "org.tukaani:xz:$xzLibraryVersion",
    "commons-io:commons-io:$commonsIoVersion",
    "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:$commonsCompressVersion",
    "com.lapots.gradle.plugins.appenv:gradle-app-environment-plugin:0.1",
    "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:$kotlinLogginVersion"
]
buildscript.dependencies {
    classpath commonDeps
}
dependencies {
    compile commonDeps
}
```

Comment: I should add it inside plugin's `build.gradle`?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing... but if you want the same dependencies on your buildscript classpath as your compile classpath this is how you do it. If you want something else, explain yourself

Comment: I just want to get rid of same dependencies I need to add when want to use my plugin (except of course `gradle-plugin` dependency). Like for example added plugin - and do not need to add `commons-io`, `kotling-logging` etc.

Comment: If your plugin has transitive dependencies, you should NOT need to list these when using the plugin. These are transitive and will be automatically included (unless you have set `transitive = false` on the Configuration)